# What plant is this? Edible, tastes like cress

Tags: botany, species-identification

My girlfriend got this at a Turkish supermarket in Berlin. It tastes like garden cress or a bit like radish. I looked up cress varieties but couldn't find this particular leaf shape.

[image]

Comment: you might get a faster response from the cooking exchange called Seasoned Advice

Comment: I think this resembles some sort of radish (german 'Radieschen') ... Different cultivars have quite some variety in terms of leave shape, so it is difficult to tell.

Comment: @John that was a very good idea, people there suggested a variant of watercress which it most probably is. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/81309/7718